# How do I remove a heading yield a specific page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am providing the h1 into my header, but I don't want it on products/show. How do I remove it just for that page?

_header.html

```
<header>
  <h1><%= yield(:heading) %></h1>
</header>
```

Homepage

```
<% provide(:heading, 'This is the homepage heading') %>
```

products/show

```
<% provide(:heading, '') %>
```

Obviously, I could just not provide any heading for the products/show page but there is CSS styling applied to my H1 that is screwing up my design, whether there is content in the h1 tag or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only render the element if it has content:

```
<header>
  <% if content_for?(:heading) %>
    <h1><%= yield(:heading) %></h1>
  <% end %>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different partial? Put an `if`-ish statement around the header?

As-is the elements themselves will always be there, because there's no reason for them not to be.